# button with sub buttons

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover, suckerfish

I currently have 2 buttons (input submits) Save, Save & Go, and we are looking to add a 3rd, Save & Close.  Due to real estate, there's no room for a 3rd button here, so the idea is to combine them into a drop down of some sort.

I'm aware that css using A's and a hidden div is probably the better solution, however, due to the way to app is coded in the inferface it is in, these NEED to be INPUTs or BUTTONs in order for the back end (a node.js -like derrivitive) to take it.

Is there a way to make something like this?

Just show

```
|"Save"|
```

but if options exist (based on other scripted params), show a down arrow, like

```
 |"Save *down*"|
```

and have the 2 (or 1, or more) sub options appear on mouseover below it:

```
| "and go" | "and close" |
```

Critical point is that all 3 conditions must submit (may want to just save without going or closing).

Again, all 3 need to be inputs type='submit' so i'm not sure how to fanagle the hover state and such in this condition.  Normally would use lists and sublists with a:hovers and intents.

I have jquery running and in an html 5 set up, so standard front end stuff can all be used, but the back end is where it gets tricky.

Any advice on a 'better way' to suckerfish this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a select dropdown like this:

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="save">Save</option>
    <option value="save&go">Save & Go</option>
    <option value="save&close">Save & Close</option>
</select>
```

Give it 3 options, Save, Save & Go, Save & Close

Comment: Yes, that could work.  But it's not 'pretty'.  For user interface reasons, would like to solve it with buttons.

Comment: you can edit the dropdown with css so it looks pretty. this is 'i think' the best option

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a design issue to me. Just have a "Save" button. On saving it, display a dialogue box having the "Go" and "Close" buttons. You can have "X(dialogue close)" on the right top of the dialogue box in case the user does not want to select either of the "Go" and "Close" buttons.